# (Xcode 6 beta / Swift) performSegueWithIdentifier has delay before segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I'm just learning Ios programming for the first time, with Swift and Xcode 6 beta.

I am making a simple test app that should call an API, and then segue programmatically to a different view to present the information that was retrieved.

The problem is the segue. In my delegate method `didReceiveAPIResults`, after everything has been successfully retrieved, I have:

```
println("--> Perform segue")
performSegueWithIdentifier("segueWhenApiDidFinish", sender: nil)
```

When the app runs, the console outputs `--> Perform segue`, but then there is about a 5-10 second delay before the app actually segues to the next view. During this time all the UI components are frozen.

I'm a little stuck trying to figure out why the segue doesn't happen immediately, or how to debug this!

Heres The Full View controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, APIControllerProtocol {

    @lazy var api: APIController = APIController(delegate: self)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func didReceiveAPIResults(results: NSDictionary) {

        println(results)

        println("--> Perform segue")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("segueWhenApiDidFinish", sender: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func getData(sender : AnyObject){

        println("--> Get Data from API")
        api.getInfoFromAPI()

    }
}
```

And my API controller:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

protocol APIControllerProtocol {
    func didReceiveAPIResults(results: NSDictionary)
}

class APIController: NSObject {

    var delegate: APIControllerProtocol?

    init(delegate: APIControllerProtocol?) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }


    func getInfoFromAPI(){

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Bob+Dylan&media=music&entity=album")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            if(error) {
                println("There was a web request error.")
                return
            }

            var err: NSError?

            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.    MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary

            if(err?) {
                println("There was a JSON error.")
                return
            }

            self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(jsonResult)
        })
        task.resume()


    }    
}
```

UPDATE: Got this working based on Ethan's answer. Below is the exact code that ended up getting the desired behavior. I needed assign `that` to `self` to have access to self inside the `dispatch_async` block.

```
let that = self

if(NSThread.isMainThread()){
    self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(jsonResult)

}else
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        println(that)
        that.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(jsonResult)
    }
}
```

Interestingly, this code does not work if I remove the `println(that)` line! (The build fails with `could not find member 'didReceiveAPIResults'`). This is very curious, if anyone could comment on this...

Comment: I think the 'println()' compilation issue is just a Beta side-effect. I got tons of those weird-ish side-effects. Still a Beta. So... Thanks for the question. Quite interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are not on the main thread when calling

```
self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(jsonResult)
```

If you ever are curious whether you are on the main thread or not, as an exercise, you can do `NSThread.isMainThread()` returns a bool.

Anyway, if it turns out that you are not on the main thread, you must be! Why? Because background threads are not prioritized and will wait a very long time before you see results, unlike the mainthread, which is high priority for the system.  Here is what to do... in `getInfoFromAPI` replace

```
self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(jsonResult)
```

with

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue())
{
    self.delegate?.didReceiveAPIResults(jsonResult)
}
```

Here you are using GCD to get the main queue and perform the UI update within the block on the main thread.

**But be wear**, for if you are already on the main thread, calling `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue())` will wait FOREVER (aka, freezing your app)... so be aware of that.

Comment: You could also use `dispatch_async`, and this will avoid the deadlock.

Comment: You mean dispatch_sync?

Comment: No. I mean instead of `dispatch_sync`, use [`dispatch_async`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_async.3.html). Calling `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` from the main thread causes a deadlock. `dispatch_async` does not .

Comment: Yea but I think his problem is because he's on the background thread, I am 99% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have a delay problem with segue from a UITableView. I have checked and I appear to be on the main thread. I checked "NSThread.isMainThread()" during prepareForSegue. It always returns true.

I found a solution on Apple Developer forums! https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5861

This person says it is a bug in iOS 8.

I followed their suggestion to add a line of code to didSelectRowAtIndexPath...... Despatch_async.....

It worked for me, hopefully you too.